# Links work in Chrome but not IE9 or Firefox

Tags: hyperlink

In Chrome everything works perfectly on a website page, the relevant part of whose source code I've copied below. However, in IE9 or Firefox (I have not checked Opera or Safari) the top and left-side navigation links do not work. The nonworking links, two of which have drop-down menus, rapidly flicker between two link texts when the mouse hovers over them. The links also toggle between link texts when you click on them in IE9 and Firefox. They do not link to other pages in those browsers. Oddly, the similarly formatted footer navigation links on the same page (also below) DO work correctly in all three browsers. After researching possible fixes I don't think this is a CSS, style tag, DOCTYPE or javascript issue, but I'm not positive. Can anyone suggest a fix?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>The Animal Union - Home</title>
<link href="css/mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<div id="navi">
<strong>
<ul >
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>                          
<li><a href="about.html">About</a>
<ul></strong>
<li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
<li><a href="activities.html">Activities</a></li>
<li><a href="board.html">Board</a></li>  
</ul>           
<li> <strong>
<a href="donate.html">Donate</a> </strong>    
<ul>
<li><a href="noncash-gifts.html">Noncash&nbsp;Gifts</a></li>
<li><a href="matching-gifts.html">Matching&nbsp;Gifts</a></li>
 <li><a href="estate-planning.html">Estate&nbsp;Planning</a></li>
</ul>                                
<li><strong><a href="volunteer.html">Volunteer</a></li>                     
<li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>                          
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact </a></li>                       
<li><a href="links.html">Links</a></strong></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
<div class="wrapper_leftpanel">
<div id="navi_drop">
<ul >
<li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>                          
<li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>                      
<li><a href="donate.html">DONATE</a></li>                      
<li><a href="volunteer.html">VOLUNTEER</a></li>                      
<li><a href="shop.html">SHOP</a></li>                          
<li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>                       
<li><a href="links.html">LINKS</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
<div class="footer">
<ul style="text-align:right;">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>   
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="donate.html">Donate</a></li>      
<li><a href="volunteer.html">Volunteer</a></li>       
<li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>     
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>        
<li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you put something on jsfiddle.net that demonstrates the problem? Try to narrow it down to a minimal case.

Comment: The links are indeed working in FF and IE. I just pasted your code in fiddle i.e http://jsfiddle.net/YFtQU/ and checked them. Tt works perfectly. Put CSS and JS also to know the issue further as HTML is not the issue.